# Node process commiunication

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have created a child process for CPU intensive work. My code is totally working fine. My problem is communication between those two(main and child processes) process taking considerable amount of time(1 to 2 Seconds). This effects the performance. Is there a any way to improve that? Or is it normal behavior ?

Comment: No, it's not normal behavior because Node is fast and yes, there's a way to improve that. Problem solved :)

Comment: Can you post your code